# C++: Text File's Extensions?

Tags: c++, text, fstream

When i use text files for input and output using `fstream` filestream,  the file extension used is `.txt`

I have seen people use instead of `.txt`:

They use `.DAT` and still they open it in a text editor as if it were a text file.

So is `DAT` a text file extension and are there what are all the extensions i can use with text files.?

Comment: anything can be used as file extension for any type of file. text files are also files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: text files can have any extension you want, including NO extension. You can take somefile.txt and rename it to somefile.XYZPDQ if you feel like it. It will still be a text file.

That's from a pure C++ language perspective. At the operating system level, a file extension may be associated with a certain program type (you might have .mp4 videos open in a video player, for example). But you can still call any text file anything you want. Nothing stops you from doing this.

Answer (score 2):

An extension is just part of file name. There is no difference what extension you use `DAT` or `TXT`. I mean, extensions help to people to recognize the file type, only to people.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any extension, but :

- using `.txt`, you usually give a hint that the file can be opened in a text editor (like vim or notepad) and will be readable by humans
- using `.dat`, you usually give a hint that the file is **binary** and cannot be opened with a text editor. One should use a special program (maybe yours ;) or an hexadecimal binary editor, and its content will not be easily readable or modifiable.
- another common extension you may use is `.csv` for comma-separated-values files (even when not using comma but tabs or anything), than can be opened either in a text editor or in a spreadsheet app like openoffice of excel.
- windows users often use `.ini` extension to hint that the file is a text file (viewable in a text editor) containing some key/value paramters like `ConfirmBeforeExit=true`. By extension, it is used for any text file containing parameters.
- another one is `.log`, hinting that the file is a text file, containing the log of execution of something. A linux user will then immediately do a `tail -f foo.log` while the app is running to look for problems.

By the way, using upper case extensions like TXT or DAT is a reminder of old DOS time and is now considered bad style. Just use lower case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any extension, because it does not matter. The `.dat` extension is usually used for binary data, so it may not be obvious for users of your program that it is in fact an editable text file.

Answer (score 1):

The extension has no effect on what type of data you can put in the file. For example you can use `TXT`, `DAT`, and even(not recommended) `EXE`. It's best to stick with one extension. If something is meant to be read by a human, I would use `TXT`, but `DAT` or the like to indicate otherwise.